# Counting couples of numbers

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I have no trouble believing that, if $|n| \leq J$, then $$\#\{ (j_1,j_2) \in \{ 1,...,J \} \, | \, j_1-j_2 = n \} = J-|n|,$$

but can anyone explain it a little more formally?

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can restrict to the case $n \ge 0$, since if $n \le 0$ then
$$\{ (j_1,j_2) \in \{ 1,...,J \} \, | \, j_1-j_2 = n \} = 
\{ (j_2,j_1) \in \{ 1,...,J \} \, | \, j_2-j_1 = -n \},$$
with $-n \ge 0$.

Write
$$S = \{ (j_1,j_2) \in \{ 1,...,J \} \, | \, j_1-j_2 = n \},$$
with $n \ge 0$.

Now if $(j_1, j_2) \in S$, we have $j_1 = n + j_2 > n$. Conversely, if $J \ge j_1 > n$, then take $j_2 = j_1 - n \in \{ 1, \dots , J \}$, and $(j_1, j_2)\in S$.

So there are as many pairs in $S$ as the $J - n$ values of $j_1$ from $n+1$ to $J$.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! It is almost clear, I got the whole idea, but I don't quite get the part when you say "conversely"...in both cases you're saying that $j_1 > n$, right?

Comment: @Nico, you're welcome. I first take a pair $(j_1, j_2)$ in $S$ and see that $n < j_1 \le J$. *Conversely* I show that if you have such a $j_1$, then you can complete it to a pair $(j_1, j_2)$ in $S$.

Comment: OHHHH I get it now!!! Grazie mille :)

Comment: @Nico, prego!$\ \ $